# How to fetch field "nama" from Category Table in Product Table (Laravel 8)

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, datatables, relationship

I really need a solution for this problem. I'm using Laravel 8.

I am trying to fetch `nama` (*name*) field from the `kategoris` (*category*) table and show it in the `produks` (*product*) table.

[image]

#### View Blade with JS code in the end

```php
@extends('back.index')

@section('content')
    <main>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="mt-4">Produk</h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href={{ route('home') }}>Dashboard</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Produk</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    DataTables is a third party plugin that is used to generate the demo table below. For more information about DataTables, please visit the
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://datatables.net/">official DataTables documentation</a>
                    .
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <i class="fas fa-table mr-1"></i>
                    DataTable Example
                    @auth
                    <a href="{{ route('produks.create') }}" class="btn btn-info float-right">Tambah Produk</a>
                    @endauth

                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="produks-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Kode</th>
                                    <th>Nama</th>
                                    <th>Kategori</th>
                                    <th>Updated At</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Kode</th>
                                    <th>Nama</th>
                                    <th>Kategori</th>
                                    <th>Updated At</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
@endsection

@push('scripts')
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#produks-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'produk/json',
            columns: [
                { data: 'kode', name: 'kode' },
                { data: 'nama', name: 'nama',
                    fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<a href='/kategoris/"+oData.id+"'>"+oData.nama+"</a>");
                    }
                },
                { data: 'kategori', name: 'kategori.nama'},
                { data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
            ]
        });
    });
    </script>
@endpush
```

I already look for solutions for several days, but I still get this error message.

[image]

#### Product Model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produk extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $casts = [
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y, H:i:s'
    ];

    public function Produk()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kategori::class, 'kategori_id');
    }
}
```

#### Category Model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kategori extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y, H:i:s'
    ];

    public function Kategori()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Produk::class);
    }
}
```

#### Product Controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Produk;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use Yajra\Datatables\DataTables;

class ProdukController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function json()
    {
       return Datatables::of(Produk::with('Kategori')->get())->make(true);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('back.produk.show');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong while naming model functions.

**Category Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kategori extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $casts = [
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y, H:i:s'
    ];

    public function Produk() //Here
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Produk::class);
    }
}
```

**Product Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produk extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $casts = [
        'updated_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y, H:i:s'
    ];

    public function Kategori() //Here
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kategori::class, 'kategori_id');
    }
}
```